# What does "exported" means in drozer framework?

Tags: android

When we run `app.package.attacksurface` in drozer, it shows exported activities, content providers etc. I understand it means that they could be vulnerable, but why do they call it "exported"?

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the [Drozer Framework User Guide](https://labs.f-secure.com/assets/BlogFiles/mwri-drozer-user-guide-2015-03-23.pdf), specifically *Chapter 3.3 Identify the Attack Surface*:

> For the sake of this tutorial, we will only consider vulnerabilities exposed through Android’s built-in mechanism for Inter-Process Communication (IPC). These vulnerabilities typically result in the leakage of sensitive data to
> other apps installed on the same device.
>
> We can ask drozer to report on Sieve’s attack surface:
>
> ```
> dz> run app.package.attacksurface com.mwr.example.sieve
> Attack Surface:
>  3 activities exported
>  0 broadcast receivers exported
>  2 content providers exported
>  2 services exported
>    is debuggable
> ```
>
> This shows that we have a number of potential vectors. **The app ‘exports’ (makes accessible to other apps) a number of activities (screens used by the app), content providers (database objects) and services (background workers).**
>
> We also note that the service is debuggable, which means that we can attach a debugger to the process, using adb, and step through the code.

As you can see, they are called "exported", because the app "exports" them to other applications, which can then make use of them.